# jquery image slider after click add image

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, click, slider

How i can add automatic array element after click function is end?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.imageOne').click(function(){
            $('.imageOne').hide();
         var link = "images/" + arrayPic(); //function get 1 random element from image name array
        $(this).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300).attr("src","/folder/" +  link);
        $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300);
});
```

So after this click function image slide from left and then gone to right side. How to add new picture after click function is over (write a code for example).

Answer (score 0):

you can use animate function like this

```
$('.imageOne').click(function(){
this.animate({
right: '300px'
},function(){

//when animation is complete

});

}
```